# numpy to spark error: TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'numpy.float64'>

Tags: pandas, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

While trying to convert a numpy array into a Spark DataFrame, I receive `Can not infer schema for type: <class 'numpy.float64'>` error.
The same thing happens with `numpy.int64` arrays.

Example:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(numpy.arange(10.))
```

> TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <class 'numpy.float64'>

Answer (score 1):

Or without using pandas:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(float(i),) for i in numpy.arange(10.)])
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick conversion to a pandas DataFrame works nicely:

```
import pandas
import numpy
df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas.DataFrame(numpy.arange(10.)))
```